# Hide SQL database from Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

How can you hide databases you do not have access rights to when logging into `SQL Server 2005 / 2008`?

Currently if a user connects, they see all the databases on the server, meaning they have to scan though the list to find their database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would need to revoke the permission 'VIEW ANY DATABASE' from the role PUBLIC (SQL SERVER 2005 onwards)

Comment: Note: this may not work for you if you can not make this user login the DBO of the database you want him to administer or if you have multiple logins you want to secure in this manner as only a single login can be the actual DBO of a database.

Answer (score 52):

After hours of trying to figure out how to create a user account which only has access to 1 DB, and can only see that DB. I think i figured it out!!!!

1. Create a user account ( **make sure its not mapped to any Database, otherwise you will get the final error Msg 15110, Level 16, State 1 and note proposed solution**)

   ```
   USE [master]
   GO
   CREATE LOGIN [us4] 
       WITH PASSWORD=N'123', 
       DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
       CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, 
       CHECK_POLICY=OFF
   ```
2. Right Click on the upper section of the SQL (SQLSERVER Name)>`Properties`>`Permissions`>Click on the `user account`, and select `Deny` to view databases.

   ```
   use [master]
   GO
   DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [us4]
   ```
3. Right Click on the newly created DB, Properties,Files, and change the Owner to the newly created account.(**important note**:  `ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [us4]` **does not work**)

   ```
   USE [dbname]
   GO
   EXEC dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame = N'us4', @map = false
   ```

At this point, once the user logs in he will see the Master,tempdb and will also see the new DB which he is a DB Owner of..You may want to go to `Tools>Option` and enabled the option to hide system objects so that you don't show the master,tempdb,etc. You may also need SP1 if this option does not work

```
Msg 15110, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the database.
```

**proposed solution to Msg 15110:** to resolve above error simply delete the user from database security node and try again

Hope that helps...

Nikhil

Comment: This is nice, but what if I don't want that user to be owner of the db, yet still be able to look at it in SSMS?

Comment: I've been looking for this for a long time, thank you very much!

Comment: cool this worked for me...  friism - too much micro managing going IMO ;) can't you just fine tune this concept by denying whatever you need IE - table drops/adds, truncates, etc...

Comment: @friism have you found any way to allow db to be visible to non-owners as well?

Comment: It's astonishing that Microsoft STILL does not provide a solution for this very obvious, fundamental security & privacy issue. See this **eight year old, ACTIVE Feature Request**: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273830/need-view-definition-permissions-per-database

Comment: It works for me! Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 24):

This actually won't work the way that makes sense or that you might expect that it would.

You `REVOKE VIEW ANY DATABASE` from the public role, but then the user has to be the database owner of the database or it can't be seen, but it still can be accessed.

The problem is a Database Engine Security shortcoming and not likely to be fixed in the current or future release of SQL Server.

***Erland Sommarskog*** opened the following connect item for this a while ago, and it recently was discussed on twitter and with Microsoft by the `SQL MVP's`.

Vote for the connect and help make it more of a priority for Microsoft to fix:

[Connect Feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=273830)

Basically the permissions are stored at the database level, so it would require enumerating each database to determine if the user has connect rights to display the database in the object explorer, which is an expensive task to perform and how the older EM used to do things.

The proposes solution is for this information to be maintained at the server level as well, which is a major change.

Comment: +1, this appears to be the most complete and thorough answer so far.

Comment: Please vote in the Connect link, although it is still marked as ACTIVE even after 8+ years

Comment: Since the Connect was moved to Azure Feedback, the link mentioned above is not working anymore. The new link is https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889787-need-view-definition-permissions-per-database

Answer (score 1):

Add user to DB as Db owner after removing *VIEW ANY DATABASE* rights

This will show only the database owned by the login in SSMS.

```
USE master; GO

DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [loginname]; GO

USE [your db]; GO

DROP USER [loginname]; GO

USE master; GO

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[your db]TO [loginname]; GO
```

Note: this requires the login to exists already

Comment: Can you explain what this code does and how it differs from the other answers

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a server-side setting on MS SQL 2005 and 2008 to restrict the databases a user may see.  I found the following text at [sql-server-performance.com](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/faq/unauthorised_user_ssms_p1.aspx)

In SQL Server 2005 it is possible with a new server side role that has been created. VIEW ANY DATABASE permission is a new, server-level permission. A login that is granted with this permission can see metadata that describes all databases, regardless of whether the login owns or can actually use a particular database. Please note By default, the VIEW ANY DATABASE permission is granted to the public role. Therefore, by default, every user that connects to an instance of SQL Server 2005 can see all databases in the instance.