# What permissions should be granted to the remote user to do anything with "the database" and no other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions, sql-server-express

What permissions should be granted to the remote user to do anything with the database "123" in SQL Server 2005 Express using [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) Express such that the remote user cannot do anything to any other database?

I would also like that the remote user cannot see the other databases. 
That is "123" is for the user login using SQL authentication method.
The is private.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 of both the web and the database server.

Webserver is connecting to database server.

"A answerer by nick Thomas asked what is meant by anything but later deleted his answer so here is what anything a user can do means for other answerers".

""Do anything means: create tables, delete tables, edit/update tables, insert, extract, and all related to functions on tables.
But no the user cannot drop THE DATABASE. The database drop should be restricted.

Insert, update, and delete on table.

Table create, alter, and drop.

Table copy, database backups.
""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this closely related (identical?) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935018/hide-sql-database-from-management-studio).

Comment: thanks. what about permissions? to grant the user? to do anything with his database.

and its related but not identical.
thankyou

Comment: As far as in the database, it sounds like you can grant owner to this user.  Normally, I careful decide on all the roles a user might be in.  A lot of times, I have external reporting/integration users in datareader role, support staff in a custom administrative role which lets them do special maintenance, application administrators in an administrative role appropriate to the application (execute on admin-only SPs like add new user, approvals, etc.) and application users in a user-only role (execute on all application SPs like add order, add product etc).  Usually few with table access.

Comment: yes thats it careful and only the necessary permissions but how, there are many boxes to tick in sql server management studio!.
cannot one box do the trick?

have add any edit. also commenting please guide me accordingly to this requirement of user "can dos"
thanks

edit is

"""do anything means -create tables, delete tables, edit/update tables, insert, extract, and all related to functions on tables. but no the user cannot drop THE DATABASE the database drop should be restricted.

insert update delete on table

table create alter drop,

table copy, database backups. """

Comment: @user287745 I would think owner is sufficient.