# Don't show databases which are not allowed to access - MS SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 40 database attached to my MS SQL Server 2014 Instance.
I need to create a new user with Read-Only access to 1 database only. He can't even see the names of databases attached to my instance.

I have already applied a solution i found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10219004/4728323  But this gives the read-only access to 1 database only. But the names of my other databases are visible when login with that new user (Access is not allowed, but db names are visible in the database list).

Comment: Don't try things at random. Undestand how things work *first* in order to understand what is relevant and what is not. The question you linked to isn't. That code is essentially the same thing the Add User dialog produces. It has *nothing* to do with **multi-tenant databases**.

Comment: In this case, what you need is [partially contained databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases). In these databases logins are stored in the database itself instead of the server. A database login can't connect to any other database or even see if there are any

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Is this gona work for SQL 2014?

Comment: You can read the links

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to achieve.

Contained Databases are available from MS SQL 2012 to onward.

1- Change the MS SQL Server instance setting by Clicking on the Server Name in the Object Explorer.

2- Go to Advanced Tab in the Properties window.

3- Set the property "Enable Contained Properties" to "True", Click "Ok".

4- Now Go the properties of your desired Database by right clicking on the database.

5- To to the "Options" tab and Set the "Containment Type" to "Partial".

6- Now Right click on users node inside the database and add user, select the "SQL User with Password" option and create the new user.

Source of Information:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2428/sql-server-2012-contained-database-feature/

Answer (score 0):

As specified in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189077(v=sql.105).aspx, "By default, the VIEW ANY DATABASE permission is granted to the public role. Therefore, by default, every user that connects to an instance of SQL Server can see all databases in the instance."

To accomplish what you want, you should revoke the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission for the `public` role:

```
REVOKE VIEW ANY DATABASE TO public
```

Alternatively, you can deny this permission only to that user:

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO YourRestrictedUser
```